# Why the random-looking keys in MDN's web worker example?

Tags: javascript

This question refers to an [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Example_2_Advanced_passing_JSON_Data_and_creating_a_switching_system) of the use of web workers in the MDN documentation.

Throughout this example, several "random looking" strings are used as keys: "vo42t30", "rnb93qh", "bk4e1h0", "ktp3fm1", ...

```
oWorker.onmessage = function (oEvent) {
  if (oEvent.data instanceof Object && oEvent.data.hasOwnProperty("vo42t30") &&
      oEvent.data.hasOwnProperty("rnb93qh")) {
    oListeners[oEvent.data.vo42t30].apply(oInstance, oEvent.data.rnb93qh);
  } else {
    this.defaultListener.call(oInstance, oEvent.data);
  }
};
```

What's the rationale for using such strings?

(I can imagine that some real-world code may use this sort of string as a form of obfuscation, but since *it makes no sense to obfuscate a didactic example like this one*, I figure that there must be some other explanation.)

Perhaps a better way to phrase the question would be: is there a problem with using human-readable strings (e.g. "methodName") for such web worker keys?

Comment: It looks like the code is using these as unique identifiers so the _messages_ go to the correct destination. It's not clear at all to me why these specifically were chosen, I'd just use a simple prefix and incrementing index if I needed this kind of thing, and probably have them as values instead of keys, e.g. `target: "worker-1"`, `target: "worker-2"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the example is used to create a special type of web worker.

This special worker checks if the message has some key, if it does, the worker handles the message in a special way.

Not all messages are going to have this special key. The messages that don't have that key should be handled normally. This other type of message could have keys named after the user input, for example.

Since we don't know what keys a regular message will have, and we have to make sure that our key is not going to be used by regular messages, we pick a very distinctive key, in this case gibberish, hoping it won't be used as key in a regular message.

One problem with this approach is that if the keys comes from user input, then the user could trigger an unexpected behaviour by sending our gibberish as input.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I really can't follow what you're saying.  It would be helpful to see an example of the type of scenario that this strategy (of using gibberish for keys) is trying to avoid.  Also, I realize that you are not necessarily advocating the strategy you describe, but rather just proposing an explanation for somebody else's code, so please, don't take my next question (in the next comment) as a criticism of you.  I just want to make sure that ...

Comment: (cont'd) ...I am not misunderstanding you.  To the extent I follow what you're saying, it sounds to me analogous to the idea of using gibberish sequences of characters *for **all** the identifiers in a program*, as insurance against the possibility that a future version of the ECMA standard introduces a new reserved keyword that collided with one of our identifiers.  Would this be a fair analogy, and if not, what's the crucial difference between the two scenarios?

Comment: So the function QueryableWorker can be used to create web workers. If the data has a special key then, this worker is going to do something special. Since you can use that same worker as a regular worker passing random data, you need to make sure that random data is not going to trigger that special behaviour. I will try to make my answer more clear.